# scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor deprecated in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, ios7, deprecated, uicolor

```
+ (UIColor *)scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor
```

method is deprecated in iOS 7 what should I use instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whatever you like. There is no default texture anymore for scrollviews in iOS7. Backgrounds are solid colors. Pick one of those or create your own UIImage as background texture.

Comment: @Bhumit That's what this site if fore. Even better than a "thanks": tick the "accepted" check mark.

Comment: i will , seems like stackoverflow has some minimum time frame , before which i can not accept the answer :)

Comment: Ah. That was new to me. Thanks for letting me know.